# How do i download the 3 latest files from a ftp server using an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, ftp

## **How Do i download the 3 latest files from the ftp server**

*i have tried using`(array_slice($contents, -3, 3, true)`and that worked fine on the `var_dump`for showing the content, here is only the 3 latest files shown*

**I Need the 3 files to be downloaded and saved by these names on my local computer`pv_inverter_1` and `pv_inverter_2` and `pv_inverter_3`**

Can i also use `array_slice(???, -3, 3, true)` to do so ???.

```
// get contents of the current directory
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");

// output $contents
var_dump (array_slice($contents, -3, 3, true));

$mostRecent = array(
'time' => 0,
'file' => null

);


foreach ($contents as $file) {
// get the last modified time for the file
$time = ftp_mdtm($conn_id, $file);

if ($time > $mostRecent['time']) {
    // this file is the most recent so far
    $mostRecent['time'] = $time;
    $mostRecent['file'] = $file;
    }
}

 if (ftp_get($conn_id, "pv_inverter_1.csv", $mostRecent['file'],FTP_BINARY)) {

     echo "Files Successfully Downloaded\n";
 }    

 else {

    echo "There was a problem\n";
}
```

Comment: Where does `$contents` get defined? Also why slice `$mostRecent` to 3 when it only has 2 in it? Your code example is ... lacking something, or...

Comment: hi it is specified further up in the code i just did not include it `// get contents of the current directory
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");`

`// output $contents
var_dump (array_slice($contents, -3, 3, true));`

Comment: Please add that to your question. Not in comments.

Comment: okay thanks i will

Comment: So do you want to download the latest three (based on timestamp) out of all files in a folder? Or the latest of those three last? Or what? Your question pretty confusing. `array_slice` won't give you 3 latest files. It will give you last 3 files in the listing.

Comment: hi the latest files are listed as the last three thats why why i thought i could use it ?

Comment: When responding, you need to use `@username` tag to send notification to the recipient. Otherwise no one notices your response.

Comment: Ok, if you want to rely on the server to return files in the correct order. But then I do not understand what you ask for, ask you have all the piece done.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl se this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47712763/ftp-get-cant-open-file1-no-such-file-or-directory-in here i made a new question

Comment: I saw that, that's the only reason I came back to this one. I responded there. If you do not need an answer to this question, please delete it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download the last three files returned by the server in directory listing:

```
$files = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");

$last_3_files = array_slice($files, -3);

$i = 0;
foreach ($last_3_files as $file)
{
    if (ftp_get($conn_id, "pv_inverter_$i.csv", $file, FTP_BINARY))
    {
        echo "$file downloaded\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "There was a problem downloading $file\n";
    }
    $i++;
}
```

---

Though note that *"last"* and *"latest"* is not the same.